# .Net windows .exe Application gives an error after installation

Tags: c#, .net, exe

I have prepared an executable file using setup factory.The installation part works perfect but when i open my exe file on desktop or in the installed directory i see an error which is this

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/06cfc.png

Any help would be highly appreciated...Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i didn't installed CRRedist2008_x86.msi(Crystal report) in my system....It worked as soon as i installed it...Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: can anybody tell me how can i open my application without installing crystal report.msi??

Comment: Like I said, a missing assembly could be causing your crash : ) I'm not aware of a way to compile and load with a missing assembly. I would post this as a separate question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

From this image you can't tell what's going on. Thats a general crash. Check the event log. You could attempt to turn on Fusion Logging to see if an assembly is missing which could be causing the crash. Also File Monitor can help you see whats being loaded as well, but I would try Fusion first.
See
[Enable Assembly Bind Failure Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

Ok; link's working now. I would recommend that you wrap your applications main window code in a try catch with a messagebox or some logging to trace that exception out in detail.

So, in Visual Studio, change your Program.cs to be like:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
       try{
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
       } catch(Exception ex){
          MesasgeBox.Show(ex.ToString());
       }
    }
```

Comment: After installing crystal report.msi i am able to run the app. how can i open my application without installing crystal report.msi??

Comment: Well, your app must have a dependency on Crystal Reports or part thereof. From the sounds of it, you would probably need to remove this dependency (check project References in Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at to the Windows event viewer (Control Panel -> Admin tools -> Event viewer)

Under Windows Logs -> Application, the .NET runtime should have added an entry for your application with details of the exception. This might help pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could also attach a remote debugger to see whats going on.

Comment: Thanks..After installing crystal report.msi i am able to run the app. how can i open my application without installing crystal report.msi??